# gst-rtsp-server use mulitcast udp source problem

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp

i got a udp multicast source at 238.0.0.1:1235.
it can play well with this command.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -m udpsrc  address="238.0.0.1" port=1235 !tsdemux !h264parse !queue !avdec_h264 !queue !d3dvideosink sync=false
```

but when i use gst-rtsp-server to create a factory like this:

```
gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch(factory,
                                      "( udpsrc address=238.0.0.1 port=1235 !tsdemux !queue ! h264parse !queue ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )");
```

and use this command to play on the client side,no video display and give me a error "Could not read from resource"

```
gst-launch-1.0 -m rtspsrc location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test !rtph264depay !queue  !decodebin !queue !d3dvideosink sync=false
```

to make it work as i expect,i have to do this:
first,retransmission udpsrc

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc address=238.0.0.1 port=1235 !queue  !udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

then,on rtsp server side:

```
gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch(factory,
                                      "( udpsrc address=127.0.0.1 port=5000 !tsdemux !queue ! h264parse !queue ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )");
```

server computer can receive udp multicast data, confirmed with updtest tool.
why i can't use multicast source to make a factory in rtsp-server?
is that a forbidden behaviour or i misunderstand something?

Comment: Have you been able to solve your problem? I have posted a very similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65203969/does-gstreamer-gst-rtsp-server-accept-udpsrc-rtp

Comment: yes, i sloved this problem.see here https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/blob/master/examples/test-multicast.c