# Does gstreamer gst-rtsp-server accept udpsrc (RTP)?

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp

I want to input an RTP stream into a gstreamer gst-rtsp-server. For initial tests I use the [test-launch.c example from github](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/blob/1.14/examples/test-launch.c) (version 1.14).

When I compile it and use it, it works well with the default example it works as expected and I can see a stream (for example using vlc player) at rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test:

```
./test-launch "( videotestsrc ! x264enc ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )"
```

But if I provide an RTP udp stream using

```
  gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720 ! x264enc ! video/x-h264, stream-format=byte-stream ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

and I use the test-launch example to play this stream using udpsrc on this port using

```
./test-launch "( udpsrc port=5000 caps='application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264' ! rtph264depay ! rtph264pay name=pay0 )"
```

there is no rtsp stream available. Is there any issue or misconception from my side with [`gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gst-rtsp-server/rtsp-media-factory.html?gi-language=c#gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch), when put it up in a way like the latter?

```
gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch (factory, "( "
  "udpsrc port=5000 "
  "caps='application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, "
  "clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264'" ")");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. The single quotes seem not to be escaped successfully . The following combination of command works with the test-launch example.

Provide RTP udp stream from a camera connected to /dev/video0

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! "video/x-raw,is-live=true,latency=0" ! x264enc ! "video/x-h264" ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000 sync=false
```

Use the test-launch example with (escaped) double quotes

```
./test-launch "( udpsrc port=5000 caps=\"application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264\" ! rtph264depay ! rtph264pay name=pay0 )"
```

stream ready at rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test

Open the rtsp stream using gstreamer (which might also be done by vlc player)

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test uridecodebin0::source::latency=1000
```

Accordingly a correct line of c-code to launch this kind of pipeline would be

```
gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch (factory, "( "
  "udpsrc port=5600 "
  "caps = \"application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H264\" ! "
  "rtph264depay ! rtph264pay name=pay0 " ")");
```